# Find intersection of polygon and order by line

Tags: c#, geometry, polygon, intersection

I was wondering if there is a method to order intersection points in a list based on the direction of the intersected line.

Here is a picture to get the idea:

[image]

The red numbers are the polygon lines which exist in a List.
Then I have another List with lines which are parallels of one polygon line intersecting the polygon at a certain offset (image shows parallels of poly line nr. 4).
Iterating through them I get the intersections points displayed in black numbers.

My problem now is that I would like to have the intersection points ordered like shown in the picture. But when iterating through every parallel the order of the intersections found changes at the 22nd intersection point.
Because the algorithm finds the intersection at poly line 1 first because I'm going through the list.

I hope you know what I mean.
I would like to find the intersection points always in the same pattern like shown.

The only idea I came up with is to transform the current line on the coordinate axis and then sort the 2 intersections by x-value but I assume that this is very bad...

I'd appreciate every answer which leads me to the solution.
Thanks in advance

Here's my code snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parallelLines.Count; i++)
{
            for (int j = 0; j < polyLines.Count; j++)
            {
                var actual = ber.LineSegementsIntersect(
                    parallelLines[i].v1,
                    parallelLines[i].v2,
                    polyLines[j].v1,
                    polyLines[j].v2,
                    out intersection);

                // if intersection is found
                if (actual)
                {
                      intersections.Add(intersection);    
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Sort your intersection lines by their distance from the original line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iterate through the lines first in an outer loop, then for each line get the 2 points in the specific order you want.

Modify your code to put the two found itxns in temporary list, instead of directly into intersections collection - then, in between the inner and outer loop add those two intx objects to the intersections collection in the proper order ((the one with smaller x value first, or whatever rule you want)

like this:  (Assume `IntersectionType` is the declared type of your Intersection object)

```
 for (int i = 0; i < parallelLines.Count; i++)
 {
        var pair = new List<IntersectionType>();
        for (int j = 0; j < polyLines.Count; j++)
        {
            var actual = ber.LineSegementsIntersect(
                parallelLines[i].v1,
                parallelLines[i].v2,
                polyLines[j].v1,
                polyLines[j].v2,
                out intersection);

            // if intersection is found
            if (actual) pair .Add(intersection);                    
        }
        intersections.Add(pair.OrderBy(i=>i.XValue).First());
        intersections.Add(pair.OrderByDescending(i=>i.XValue).First());
 }
```

oh, by the way,  the variable `actual`, if it is what I think it is, should be renamed as `found`,  or, better, refactor as:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < parallelLines.Count; i++)
 {
        var pair = new List<IntersectionType>();
        for (int j = 0; j < polyLines.Count; j++)
            if(ber.LineSegementsIntersect(
                 parallelLines[i].v1, parallelLines[i].v2,
                 polyLines[j].v1, polyLines[j].v2,
                 out intersection))
               pair .Add(intersection);
        intersections.Add(pair.OrderBy(i=>i.XValue).First());
        intersections.Add(pair.OrderByDescending(i=>i.XValue).First());
 }
```

Comment: don't know exactly what you mean. I added my code to the question

Comment: ok, I see how you are doing it... Modify it to put the two found itxns in temporary list, instead of directly into intersections collection -  then, in between the inner and outer loop add those two intx objects to the intersections collection in the proper order ((the one with smaller x value first, or whatever rule you want)